# Maintaining "the proper" distance between labels for tick marks and the axes

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a graph for a piecewise function with labels for the tick marks on the axes.  I used the following options for the `axis` environment so that the labels do not interfere with the graph.  (I want the labels to appear to be in the foreground.)

```
axis on top
ticklabel style={font=\tiny, circle, fill=white, inner sep=0pt}
```

It seems that `inner sep=0pt` makes the labels on both axes too close to the axes.  How do I keep the default settings for the distance between the labels for tick marks and the axes?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=3.5in, width=3.5in, axis equal image, axis on top, clip=false,
    xmin=-3.5,xmax=4.5,
    ymin=-2.5,ymax=2.5,
    restrict y to domain=-2.5:2.5,
    xtick={-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4}, ytick={-2, -1, 1, 2},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny, circle, fill=white, inner sep=0pt},
    xticklabels={\makebox[0pt][r]{$-$}3, \makebox[0pt][r]{$-$}2, \makebox[0pt][r]{$-$}1, 1, 2, 3, 4},
    yticklabels={-2, -1, , 1, 2},
    yticklabels={-2, -1, 1, 2},
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    axis line style={shorten >=-12.5pt, shorten <=-12.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, xshift=12.5pt, anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, yshift=12.5pt, anchor=south west}
]


\addplot[samples=2, blue, domain=-3:0] {-x - 2};
\addplot[samples=501, blue, domain=0:4] {sqrt(4 - (x - 2)^2) - 2};

\draw[fill=blue] (-3,1) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw[fill=blue] (0,-2) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw[fill=blue] (4,-2) circle [radius=1.5pt];

\coordinate (A) at (-2.75,0.75);
\coordinate (B) at (-2.25,1.25);

\end{axis}

%A "pin" is drawn between the label for the graph and the point (7, 1/8) on the graph.
\draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (A) -- (B);
\node[blue, anchor=south west, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at ($(B)$) {$y = f^{\prime}(x)$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

What you need is to increase  `outer sep` distance

```
ticklabel style={font=\tiny, circle, fill=white, inner sep=0pt,outer sep=3pt}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know the value that would return the tick labels to their default distances?